# How to add a member into an Azure AD Group using Python/Azure Databricks?

Tags: python, azure, powershell

I'm adding a bunch of Object IDs for multiple service principals as members into an Azure AD Group. Doing this using Azure Powershell is very stright forward and easy. I just run the below loop as a powershell script:

```
foreach ($user_object_id in $service_principals)
{
  Add-AzADGroupMember -TargetGroupObjectId "$Base_AD_group_ObjectId" -MemberObjectId "$user_object_id"

}
```

But we're making changes to our infra and so now I need to do the same thing using Python instead. I use Azure Databricks for our python scripts, and I'm unable to figure out how to do this in Python/Databricks. (I can't simply call the powershell script from inside a python script in this case. I believe that's not possible with Azure Databricks.)

Any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

> You can generate access token using `msal` library and call **Microsoft Graph API** to add a member into an Azure AD Group.

I registered one Azure AD application and granted consent to **API permissions** as below:

[image]

I have one Azure AD group name **`SriGroup01`** with below properties:

[image]

To generate access token using `msal` library and call **Microsoft Graph API**, I used below python code and got **response** like this:

```py
import msal
import requests

client_id = "appId"
client_secret= "secret"
tenant_id = "tenantId"
authority = f"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant_id}"
scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']

# User and group details
service_principals = ['user_id_1', 'user_id_2']
base_ad_group_object_id = 'group_id'

graph_url = f'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/'

app = msal.ConfidentialClientApplication(client_id, client_secret, authority=authority)

token = app.acquire_token_for_client(scopes)

if 'access_token' in token:
    access_token = token['access_token']
    #print(access_token)

    # Add users to the group
    for user_object_id in service_principals:
        add_member_url = f'{graph_url}/groups/{base_ad_group_object_id}/members/$ref'
        headers = {
            'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        data = {
            '@odata.id': f'{graph_url}/directoryObjects/{user_object_id}'
        }

        response = requests.post(add_member_url, headers=headers, json=data)

        if response.status_code == 204:
            print(f'\nSuccessfully added user {user_object_id} to the group.')
        else:
            print(f'Failed to add user {user_object_id} to the group. Status code: {response.status_code}')
else:
    print('Failed to acquire access token.')
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I checked the same in Portal, users added successfully to the group like below:

[image]